# Styling SELECT option dropdown background, width and font

Tags: html, css, forms, html-select

I have a problem here.

There's a select element with some options, and I wonder if it's possible to change the dropdown's background, width and font.

The sample markup is:

```
<form action="">
<span>Show</span>   
<select name="cars" id="indicator-filter-options">
    <option value="all" selected>Cars</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I didn't paste my css because it's written in SASS using variables.

Is it possible to achieve a similarly looking background and hover effect as in here:

[The dropdown design I'm trying to achieve is HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cX5k.png)

Comment: You need to add a jquery plugin fir this, and this might be helpful for you https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Thanks man I'm going to check this out.

Comment: you can use something like sass on fiddle, or just replace the variables on the places.

Comment: most of these inputs that you see, they don't use select tag at all. they use divs with combination of css and js. it's really better if you use an already available library for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot style dropdown options like that unless you use unordered list. The demo below might give you an idea.

```
<ul><li>Option One</li></ul>
```

[View Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mlsenica/zhyzrb82/2/)

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. I used select2.github.io for this for a complete solution. Thanks for response, Maria.